# How to change rendered value in Jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using a datatables jquery plugin. Now I need to change value of column 2 after ajax loaded. But unfortunately my code doesn't work. I can't find solution in manual and internet. Below code how I doing:

```
var productTable = $("#productTable").dataTable({
        bSort: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        bPaginate: true,
        sAjaxSource: '/getAll',

        columns: [
            {"data": "DT_RowId"},
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {

                    var desc = full.value;
                    return  '<span class="smallDesc">' + desc + '</span>';
                }
            }],

 "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {

            var api = this.api();
            api.cell("#20300006", 0).data('newData'); // it works               
            api.cell("#20300006", 1).data('newData2'); //dosen't works
            api.draw();
});
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: there is no error, result is column 1 change ok but column 2 doesn't change

Comment: what is api? what is the cell function? maybe you use the same id: #20300006?

Comment: according manual I do ok https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.data%28%29

Comment: You should use a debugger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: ok I found soulution, need to add data param to columns array